# No data returned when modularizing API in JS

Tags: javascript, module, liferay-aui

I am trying to modularize my JS code by creating an API module, where I can retrieve all required data using Liferay's AUI ajax features. Currently I have this:

```
var API = (function() {
        var getAsistencias = function(idEdicion, periodo) {

            AUI().use('aui-io-request', function(A) {
                A.io.request('myapiaddress', {
                    method : 'post',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data : {
                        _mypackage_WAR_myportlet_periodo : periodo,
                        idEdicion : idEdicion
                    },
                    on : {
                        success : function() {
                            data = this.get('responseData');
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        };
        return {
            getAsistencias : getAsistencias,
        }
})();
```

However when I call it like this:

```
var data = API.getAsistencias(id, dataInfo);
```

Data is always null even though in the onSuccess method it is actually retrieving the data correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Also how can I manage errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is you are not returning anything from your functions. This should be something like this

```
var API = (function() {
    var getAsistencias = function(idEdicion, periodo,callback) {

        AUI().use('aui-io-request', function(A) {
            A.io.request('myapiaddress', {
                method : 'post',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {
                    _mypackage_WAR_myportlet_periodo : periodo,
                    idEdicion : idEdicion
                },
                on : {
                    success : function() {
                        data = this.get('responseData');
                        callback(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };
    return {
      getAsistencias:getAsistencias
    };
})();
API.getAsistencias(id,periodo,function(data){
 Console.log(data);
 //Do something here
});
```

Comment: sorry forgot to paste that part. I did include it in my orginal code. The problem is elsewhere: i call my function without a problem (it gets executed)

Comment: This is a asynchronous call, the data is not directly returned you need to use a callback . Will update my code with callback